# What is the ApacheDS version used by WSO2 Identity Server 4.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Pls. specify the ApacheDS version that is used by WSO2 Identity server 4.0. Is this Apache DS 2.0 or some prior versions?

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 Identity Server uses embedded Apache DS 1.5.7